# vue-router reloading App.vue on every new route

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have an App.vue file, which has a vue-router component in it that loads the content of my different pages, like this:

```
<template>
   <div>
        <router-view
        :auth="auth"
        :page_id="page_id"
        >
        </router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

I also have some AJAX calls in my created() method, which seem to be triggered every time I load a new page via the router.  Is there any way to structure things so that my created() method only gets called once when the application loads, not every time a new page within the router loads?

Comment: Please provide a sample of your code.

Answer (score 0):

One approach will be using [Navigation Guards](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#global-guards) when you create a logic to determinate when to make your Ajax calls.

Other will be using [Vuex](https://vuex.vuejs.org/), and create a state object to manage the Ajax calls, dispatch an event when the compontent had been loaded before, and bind a computed property to a getter that will contain the value if that component has been loaded previously.

Answer (score 0):

Solution was a lot simpler than I thought:

The App.vue page was using a href links hard-coded to each route.
If you switch to using

```
<router-link to="path to your route">text here</router-link>
```

instead, everything works as normal - but Vue doesn't reload the App.vue component!

Comment: Why should Vue reload the App.vue, its the entry point of the app?